# Getting Errors when try to convert png to text using Image Magick magick Test.png Test.txt

Tags: imagemagick

I'm receiving an error message:  error "Windows - No Disk  Exception Processing Message 0xc0000013 Unexpected Parameter" when I run -  magick Test.png Test.txt

The error message in the DOS window is:
Magick: unable to open image'Test2.txt' : Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537

I guess I'd describe myself as a lower intermediate programmer.  This is my 1st time asking a question here as a new member.  The first three times I did this command it worked perfectly.  But now I'm getting this error message, and I'm not doing anything different.  I really need to get these text files generated from the png files, so I hope that some can help.  Probably something very simple, but any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try on a very small image. You may be have too much data to convert to txt.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input.  I am using a small test image, and I keep getting the same error message.  I just cannot figure out what I did differently two days before when it worked perfectly - and on a much larger image too.